# Added new drive but it's stuck as "read only file system"

Tags: mount, files, filesystem, automount, drive

Bought a new drive. Expected it would be easy to install...

Shouldn't need to use commands for something every day users should be able to complete, so I followed this GUI guide:

https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-automount-a-drive-in-linux-the-gui-way-with-gnome/

I managed to write a file on the drive from an application. However, later when I attempt to change the file it says it's a read-only file system:

```
sudo chmod 777 file_name
chmod: changing permissions of file_name: Read-only file system
```

I get the same when trying to change the permissions for the mounted folder.

Interestingly when I open GParted I get an error for the new drive:

[image]

and the drive isn't shown in the drop down.

Disks application shows this:

[image]

Could someone please provide a simple solution where I am just using the GUI?

This is for Ubuntu 22.04

**Updates from comments:**

```
findmnt -T /media/ssd
TARGET     SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/media/ssd /dev/sda1 ext4   ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime
```

and

```
findmnt --fstab
TARGET      SOURCE                                                 FSTYPE OPTIONS
/           UUID=3983f8b5-04f5-4eb4-8356-5f749f7cbaa6              ext4   errors=remount-ro
/boot/efi   UUID=9450-FE9C                                         vfat   umask=0077
none        /swapfile                                              swap   sw
/media/ssd/ /dev/disk/by-uuid/c1189942-b1c5-432f-815b-cdcb40054877 auto   nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show
```

Another:

```
sudo fsck -y /dev/sda1 
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
fsck.ext2: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sda1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Comment: Please add the output of `findmnt -T /media/ssd` (while the drive/filesystem is mounted) and `findmnt --fstab`

Comment: @Raffa added to bottom of question. Thanks

Comment: Thank you ... Also, please check the logs with `journalctl -r --grep='/dev/sda'` and see if there are any recent messages that might be related to mounting `/dev/sda1` as read only.

Comment: Meanwhile, worth noting that the `nofail` mount option might prevent automatic filesystem checks for that filesystem during boot and a filesystem corruption might result in it getting mounted as read-only.

Comment: @Raffa I have to claim ignorance here, I use Linux like I use Windows..... I was expecting plug & play. What's simplest way to fix this? Drive can be reformatted, that's not a problem.

Comment: The thing is that the info you added to your question so far are inconclusive ... They could mean among other things but more importantly a defective drive, a defective cable/slot, loose drive fitting/plugging or a corrupted filesystem that needs checking/fixing with e.g.  `fsck` ... You'll need to find the culprit first and then decide ... If for example it's a corrupt filesystem, then run a filesystem checking tool on it and then remove `nofail` from `/etc/fstab` so it gets automatic checks on failure in the future and this will most likely not happen again ... But, now it's not clear to me.

Comment: @rare77:    Try this command: sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1, before sudo fsck -y /dev/sda1 .

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda1
sudo fsck -y /dev/sda1 
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/sdd 
sudo chmod -Rf 777 /media/sdd
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I encountered a problem with the second command. I've pasted the output at the bottom my question.